# Install base metrics for firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I thought this would be easy, but I can't seem to find anywhere on the firebase console for analytics metrics of the current install base. I have an iOS and android application using the firebase plugin. I can get metrics for date range, but I would like to get metrics for the current install base of users. Such as the version number that is installed or the platform on which the app is installed. Again, I see how to do this via date range, but I am not wanting that. Firebase seems to be doing simple addition for those graphs to show what the versions/platforms (etc) are being reported during those dates. I am wanting to do metrics on the current installs.

Thanks for the help!!!

I have tried searching firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a common mistake and Google didn't make it obvious enough, but Firebase UI is more of a debugging tool. Despite you having all the data, it's often is unable to report it adequately.

A solution is pretty simple - you create a GA4 account (or use an existing one) and then [connect it to your FB account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en).

GA4 will give you proper access to your data. Make sure to fix the default value for GA4's data retention unless you only need very recent data to be available.

If GA4 will seem like not enough, it supports seamless export of the raw data to BQ where you can use SQL for whatever analysis you need, or ETL the data elsewhere.